# How do I make my JavaScript answer with a third response?

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JavaScript and I created a simple script where it asks how many hours you have worked. It will then show whether or not you have worked enough, and then displays your previously entered number.

I did the first 2 lines as

```
if (hours > 18) {
    alert('You have worked enough hours, thank you,');
} else if (hours < 18) {
    alert('You have not worked enough hours.');
}
```

That worked fine. But then I added a third line:

```
else if (hours > 30) {
    alert('Wow, you have worked a lot of hours!');
}
```

That does not work.

What could be the problem? I will leave full script here:

```js
'use strict';

let hours = prompt('How many hours have you worked today?');

if (hours > 18) {
  alert('You have worked enough hours, thank you,');
} else if (hours < 18) {
  alert('You have not worked enough hours.');
} else if (hours > 30) {
  alert('Wow, you have worked a lot of hours!');
}

alert(`You have worked ${hours} hours`);
```

Comment: just put the > 30 on first place and it will work. In your case, if hours ist for example 31, it is bigger then 18, so it will print first message and quite the if

Comment: Also I think prompt returns string instead of numbers,m

Comment: Unrelated, but if the user has worked exactly 18 hours none of the conditions match. It should probably be `>= 18`.

Comment: Also you have to be quite a wizard if you can work more than 30 hours in a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to check whether hours are greater than 30 or not then you have to check with 18 because first if you check whether `hours > 18` then it will become true always when you enter hours more than 18 (includes hours > 30 also) so your check `else if (hours > 30)` never executes.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
 <html>
   <script>

     'use strict';

      let hours = prompt('How many hours have you worked today?');

      if (hours > 30) {
         alert('Wow, you have worked a lot of hours!');
      }
      else if (hours >= 18) {
         alert('You have worked enough hours, thank you,');
      }
      else if (hours < 18) {
         alert('You have not worked enough hours.');
      }

     alert(`You have worked ${hours} hours`);

  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check condition "hours > 30" first. 
Hope the code below help you

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<script>

    'use strict';

    let hours = prompt('How many hours have you worked today?');
    if (hours > 30) {

        alert('Wow, you have worked a lot of hours!');
    } 
    else if (hours > 18) {

        alert('You have worked enough hours, thank you,');
    }

    else if (hours < 18) {

        alert('You have not worked enough hours.');
    }

    alert(`You have worked ${hours} hours`);

    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move `if (hours >= 30)` at the beginning and check first.
Otherwise, it will be included in the condition `if (hours >= 18)` and never be executed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<script>

    'use strict';

    let hours = prompt('How many hours have you worked today?');

    if (hours >= 30) {

        alert('Wow, you have worked a lot of hours!');
    }
    else if (hours >= 18) {

        alert('You have worked enough hours, thank you,');
    }
    else {

        alert('You have not worked enough hours.');
    }

    alert(`You have worked ${hours} hours`);

    </script>

</html>
```